# ES6 / Typescript - Typing a value of an arrow function

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to figure out a typescript situation where I am trying to define the output of a arrow function.

```
let isThisTrue:boolean = () => {
  return true;
};

console.log(isThisTrue());
```

Can I only define a type when I am passing a value to a method? I know this example isn't really practical but I am just trying to grasp why I am unable to say that the expected output is a `boolean`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mn9efLtg/

Error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `isThisTrue` is `function`. The result value of the function is `Boolean` ([typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20isThisTrue%20%3D%20()%3Aboolean%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20true%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(isThisTrue())%3B)):

```
const isThisTrue = ():boolean => {
  return true;
};

console.log(isThisTrue());
```

Comment: Awesome, that makes more sense. I assume `const` is also used because a function should always be the same in this case.

Comment: @SBB - That's entirely up to you. If you intend to change `isThisTrue` at some point later in the code, use `let`. If you don't, then you can use `const` to A) document that fact for future maintainers of the code, and B) have the JavaScript engine enforce it (by raising an error) if you accidentally do try to change its value. :-)